# In LinkedHashMap, Does insertion order change with re-insertion when accessOrder is true

Tags: java, collections

In [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

**Note 1**. "**Insertion order is not affected** if a key is **re-inserted** into the map."

**Note 2**. "A special constructor is provided to create a linked hash map whose order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently (access-order)."

Query:

1. Does **re-insertion** (`put` method) modify **recent access** of that specified entry object or it is only `get` method which alters the **recent access**?
2. If `accessOrder` is `true` while constructing a LinkedHashMap, does "**Note 1**" statement above get contradicted and insertion order is affected?

**Update**

As per below test code, both `put` and `get` method changing access order. Then is Note 1 apparently not correct with `accessOrder = true` in LinkedHashMap constructor.

```
 public class Main
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(16, .75f, true);
        map.put(1, "A");
        map.put(2, "B");
        map.put(3, "C");
        map.put(4, "D");
        map.put(5, "E");
        System.out.println(map);// Output: {1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E}

        // get method changed access order
        String dummy = map.get(2);
        System.out.println(map);  // Output: {1=A, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E, 2=B}

        // put method changed access order
        map.put(1, "Z");
        System.out.println(map);  // Output: {3=C, 4=D, 5=E, 2=B, 1=Z}
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could easily setup a small demo code on your own to test point #1.

Comment: Updated with test case, Second query is prime concern, query 1 is mere validation for query 2

Comment: "*Does insertion order change with re-insertion when accessOrder is true*" doesn't really make sense. When we set `accessOrder` to `true` we are changing ordering of all entries in that `LinkedHashMap` from time of insertion to time of accessing. So since there is no more *insertion order* in use it can't be affected (unless I misunderstood your question).

Comment: Yes, it was little confusing at the beginning that with `accessOrder` being `true` we are setting a new ordering, and it's not as per insertion order anymore exactly which I have posted in answer already before your comment. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion order does not change when a mapping is reinserted or updated by `put` method. Both these following line as per example above will change access order but not insertion order.

```
map.put(1,"A");
map.put(1,"Z");
```

Access order, with `accessOrder = true` would change as per least recent access to most recent access, that is

```
{2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E, 1=A}
{2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E, 1=Z}
```

But Insertion order is still the same, which can be printed with `accessOrder = false`, that is

```
{1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D, 5=E}
```

So, insertion order is not changed with reinsertion, but access order changes in a LinkedHashMap.